# How to make a pure virtual function work in parent class function

Tags: c++

I just wonder how to make a pure virtual function work in parent class function, like:

```
class MapGeneric {
public:
MapGeneric();
vector<int> map(vector<int> vec) {
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++ ) {
    vec[i] = f(vec[i]);
}
return vec;}

virtual int f(int x) = 0;};#endif
```

I want to define the function f(int x) in the derived class, however, I want use it in function map(), here is my code in derived class to define the f():

```
MapTriple::MapTriple() : MapGeneric(){}
int MapTriple::f(int x) {
x = 3*x;
return x;}
```

When I write a main.cpp to test it, it compiles but not working, which still return the same vector instead of a 3 times vector.

```
using namespace std;int main() {
vector<int> a = {1,2,3};
MapGeneric* m;
m = new MapTriple;
m -> map(a);
for (int i = 0; i<a.size(); i++) {
    cout<<a[i];
}}
```

Any suggestion XD

Comment: How do you pass the vector to the `map` function? What are you doing with the vector it returns?

Comment: The function `f()` needs to be explicitly overridden within the class definition of `MapTriple` (which you haven't shown).   Simply defining it outside (not inline with) the `MapTriple` class definition is insufficient.    Bear in mind that it is not possible to call `f()` in the constructor of `MapGeneric`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here looks like it actually resides in the non-virtual function.

You're throwing away the return value from the map function, so by simply changing this line:

```
    m->map(a);
```

to one that doesn't discard the return value:

```
    a = m->map(a);
```

you should see the updated 3x vector.